# String message not fully printing on SPP server via bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

My Simple SPP server seems to be only picking up one item from my ArrayList from my MainActivity, how come it won't print it all? Also strangely when I remove the "\n" from my for loop to set final message i get "86" but when there is no "\n" nothing is printed???

android ConnectTest class

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect_test);

    temp = getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra("lightInformation");

    out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);

    out.append("\n...In onCreate()...");

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    CheckBTState();
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    out.append("\n...In onStart()...");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();



    out.append("\n...In onResume...\n...Attempting client connect...");

    // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
    BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

    // Two things are needed to make a connection:
    //   A MAC address, which we got above.
    //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
    //     UUID for SPP.
    try {
        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }

    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
    // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
    try {
        btSocket.connect();
        out.append("\n...Connection established and data link opened...");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
    out.append("\n...Sending message to server...");

    try {
        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        AlertBox("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
    }



    String finalMessage = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        finalMessage =  finalMessage  + String.valueOf(temp.get(i)) + "\n";
    }

    String message = finalMessage;



    byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
    try {
        outStream.write(msgBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
```

readout on eclipse server

```
Server Started. Waiting for clients to connect...
Remote device address: E458E7526EE3
Remote device name: SAMSUNG-SM-G920V
83
BlueCove stack shutdown completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this, not really sure why it worked but it did:
commented out this:

```
String finalMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < temp1.size(); i++) {
            finalMessage =  finalMessage  + String.valueOf(temp1.get(i)) + "\n";
        }
```

and replaced simply with this:

```
  String message = String.valueOf(temp1);
```